# How to mask an image with a composite but only where the color is black

Tags: php, imagick

I have a mask.png:

[image: mask]

And some other png image with the same dimensions:

[image]

Now I would like to mask the image with mask.png but only where the color is black on the mask image.

Desired result:

[image: desired result]

Is something like this possible with imagick if yes how?

Comment: Why isn't the white preserved? Or do you mean mask is a template, but only on the black colors. So mask can have any colors but where it's black it should "cut" out from the other image?

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with it? You also should ask a more specific question or else people will be tempted to answer only "yes"

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like to cut out the image with the mask but only where the color is black in the mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really tricky question. Usually to isolate black colors, you would simply apply a `SCREEN` composite.

```php
$image->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_SCREEN, 0, 0);
```

*But* the mask in question already has an active alpha channel, so it may be possible that transparent black values exists, and cause undesired effects.

I would suggest rebuilding the mask as a new alpha color channel. That is to say, a black-n-white image where black represents a fully opaque pixel, and white is a fully transparent pixel. Then copy the rebuilt mask as the new alpha channel.

```php
// Load resources.
$image = new Imagick('input.png');
$mask = new Imagick('mask.png');
// Create a white canvas.
$tempMask = new Imagick();
$tempMask->newPseudoImage($mask->width, $mask->height, 'XC:WHITE');
// Copy mask over canvas to replace transparent values.
$tempMask->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);
// Invert colors.
$tempMask->negateImage(true);
// Copy temporary mask as the new alpha channel.
$image->compositeImage($tempMask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
// Save results.
$image->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: output.png]